# Warning message: In scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings, : EOF within quoted string

Tags: excel, csv, rstudio

I'm a totally a beginner to Rstudio and I just want to upload a file so I can do some statistical analysis. I have been sitting with this problem for hours now. I have an excel file I want to view in R-studio but I get this message when trying to upload it as an CSV.file (both as CSV_MS-DOS and CSV_"comma delimenated")

> Warning message: In scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip,
>   nlines, na.strings, : EOF within quoted string.

What's wrong? please describe in steps how I should solve it because I'm not used to Rstudio. (I've already deleted some stuff in the excelsheet before converting to CSV: comments, formulas and centered over columns. Still doesn't work)

Tried to read the other answers in similar questions but I didn't get a thing of it. Please help!

Commands used:

```
C13<- read.csv(file.choose(), header=TRUE)
```

> Warning message: In scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip,
>   nlines, na.strings,  :   EOF within quoted string

```
C14<- read.table(file.choose(), header=TRUE, sep=",")
```

> Warning message: In scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip,
>   nlines, na.strings,  :   EOF within quoted string

```
C15<- read.delim(file.choose(), header=TRUE)
```

> Warning message: In scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip,
>   nlines, na.strings,  :   EOF within quoted string

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have an isolated single quote somewhere in the file, as in
the name O'Rourke, remove it and hopefully it will work, it did for me!

Comment: Thanks for you answer, Now 8 months later I've solved the question =)